# Find the number of subsets $S$ of $X$ (of any size) that satisfy the following property

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, relations

> Let $X=\{1,2,\dots,10\}$ define the relation $R$ on $X$ by:
>   for all $a,b\in X$, $a\mathrel{R}b \iff ab$ is even.
>
> 1) Find the number of subsets $S$ of $X$ (of any size) that satisfy  the following property:
>   $\forall a\in S,\exists b\in S,a\mathrel{R}b$. explain

I think is 5 because, $b=[2],[4],[6],[8],[10]$?

> 2) Find and simplify the number of two element subsets $S$ of $X$ that satisfy the following property $\forall a\in S,a\mathrel{R}1$

I don't quite get the question..
ty

Comment: There are more subsets. What about $\{1, 2\}$ and $\{1, 2, 3\}$?For part 2, how many 2-element subsets are there such that for every $a \in S$, $a$ is related to 1?

Comment: what is {1,2}? how do you apply it to the relation?

Comment: It is a subset of $X$ containing the elements $1, 2$. As you can see for each element, there is another element to which it is related. In $\{1,2,3\}, 1R2, 2R2, 3R2$.

Comment: I thought I already included? b=[2].. do you mean b=[1,2]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINTS:

1. A set $S\subseteq X$ has the property that $\forall a\in S\,\exists b\in S(a\,R\,b)$ if and only if $S$ contains an even number. (Why?) How many subsets of $X$ contain an even number? (You may find it easier to start by counting that subsets of $X$ that do **not** contain an even number.)
2. Note that $a\,R\,1$ if and only if $a$ is even. (Why?) How many $2$-element subsets of $X$ contain only even numbers?

Comment: can you explain why  [1,2] satisfy the condition? I don't understand what is [1,2]. I know [2]x[any a] is even, but now do you multiply [1,2]x[any a]?

Comment: @user115251: $\{1,2\}$ has the property because if $a\in\{1,2\}$, we can choose $b=2$ and be certain that $ab$ is even.

Comment: for  question 2, what is 2 element? is it {2,2}

Comment: @user115251: A $2$-element set is a set that has exactly $2$ elements. $\{1,2\}$ is a $2$-element set; $\{2,2\}$ is not, since it’s the same thing as $\{2\}$.

Comment: so is {2,3} even?

Comment: @user115251: $\{2,3\}$ isn’t an integer, so it doesn’t make sense to ask whether it’s even. It’s a two-element set, and it does have the property specified in $(1)$: no matter what $a\in\{2,3\}$ you pick, you can choose $b=2$ and be certain that $ab$ is even.

Comment: what about the number 1 in {1,2}? Does that mean as long as there is a even number in a subset, we can ignore the rest of the elements and it is even?

Comment: @user115251: Your question doesn’t really make sense. What do you mean by *it* in *and it is even*?

Comment: like {2},{4} .. are even? Christopher Liu said {1,2} also satisfy the condition, so {1,2} is even?

Comment: @user115251: $\{2\}$ and $\{4\}$ are *not* even. It doesn’t even make sense to ask whether they are even: they are not integers. $2$ and $4$ are even; the sets $\{2\}$ and $\{4\}$ are not even the kind of thing that *can* be even. Neither is $\{1,2\}$.

Comment: I think I got it now, so {2,3}, {1,4,9}...all satisfy the condition, because we can choose a even number 2 and 4 in those subsets?

Comment: and the answer is 2^10 - 2^5= 2^5?

Comment: @user115251: There are $2^{10}$ subsets of $X$ altogether, and $2^5$ of them contain no even number, so you do indeed want $2^{10}-2^5$, but that’s not equal to $2^5$.

Comment: yes, sorry its a mistake. Also, the answer for 2) is 5x4?

Comment: @user115251: Not quite: that counts each two-element set twice. For instance, you’re counting $\{2,4\}$ as ‘first $2$, then $4$’, but also as ‘first $4$, then $2$’. Order doesn’t matter, so you just want the right binomial coefficient.

Comment: oh, so its 5 choose 2?

Comment: @user115251: Yes, it is.